# 2010s(?) book with identical twins who have musical powers

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

- **Summary:** There are two identical twins who are amazing with music. They are part of a circus and when playing, odd things happen to their audience which starts attracting the wrong attention and they are then chased around by these things I think were called Executors because of their display of magical, musical powers!
- **Date Read:** 2-3 years ago!
- **Date Published:** Probably also 2-3 years ago!
- **Book Details:** Probably around 400 pages; I think hardcover; cover may have been purple-ish...
- **Author:** No idea...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The Trilogy of Two* (2015) by Juman Malouf?

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23846000-the-trilogy-of-two):

> **Identical twins Sonja and Charlotte are musical prodigies with extraordinary powers.** Born on All-Hallows-Eve, the girls could play music before they could walk. They were found one night by Tatty, the Tattooed Lady of the circus, in a pail on her doorstep with only a note and a heart-shaped locket. **They’ve been with Tatty ever since, roaming the Outskirts in the circus caravans, moving from place to place.**
>
> But lately, curious things have started to happen when they play their instruments. **During one of their performances, the girls accidentally levitate their entire audience, drawing too much unwanted attention. Soon, ominous Enforcers come after them**, and Charlotte and Sonja must embark on a perilous journey through enchanted lands in hopes of unlocking the secrets of their mysterious past.

Cover art is grey/green.

[image: whole book cover, two twins playing instruments]

---

Found with the Google query `book "identical twins" music powers circus site:goodreads.com`.